# Перестал собираться maven проект

Tags: java, maven

Проект с использование Spring, долгое время всё компилировалось а потом резко начал отказываться билдить модуль(единственный в проекте) 
[image: начал выдавать такое]
[image: также начались проблемы со всеми maven библиотеками]
[image: также все файлы из папки .mvn/wrapper выделены красным]
А всего-то хотел подключить bootstrap и добавить с

Comment: я не спец конечно, но у вас ошибка написана на первом скрине, остальные скрины непоянтно для чего вообще в вопросе.

Comment: не понятно как с ней бороться, думал может кто-то сталкивался

Comment: ну вы на ошибку нажимали? Она вас на файл с ошбкой должна направить по идее.

Comment: проблема в том что не направляет никуда, даже откат к предыдущей версии не помогает, и в интернете не могу найти ничего подобного

Comment: У вас на первом скрине в тексте ошибки указан адрес вида `http:\...` Должно быть два прямых слеша вместо одного обратного (`http://...`). Найдите где этот адрес у вас прописан, возможно исправление адреса решит вашу проблему. Возможно также адрес должен быть в кавычках.

Comment: всё-таки дело не в этом